# Logical Error in Verilog code for converting SR FF to JK FF

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have created a default design of SR FF and using module instantiation I am trying to create a JK FF from SR FF module.I am not facing any syntax error but all my outputs are comming to be 0 in all the condiitons of J and K values as I have taken datatype of q to be bit.Here is the code.

Here is the code.

```
// Design Code
module JK_FF(output reg q, input j,k,clk);

    reg qbar;
    wire qjk;
    wire s=0,r=0;
    assign qjk = q;
    SR_FF sr(s,r,clk,q,qbar);  
    assign s=j&~qjk;
    assign r=k&qjk;

endmodule

module SR_FF(input s,r,clk, output reg q, qbar);

    always@(posedge clk)
      begin 
        if(s == 1)
          begin
            q = 1;
            qbar = 0;
          end
         else if(r == 1)
          begin
            q = 0;
            qbar =1;
          end   
         else if(s == 0 & r == 0) 
          begin 
            q <= q;
            qbar <= qbar;
          end
      end

endmodule
```

```
// Testbench Code
<pre></code>
module JK_TB;
bit j,k, clk;
bit q;

    JK_FF dut(.q(q), .j(j), .k(k), .clk(clk)); 
    
    always #5 clk = ~clk;  
    
    initial 
      clk <= 0;
    
    initial begin 
      j = 0; k = 1;
      #10; j = 1; k = 0; 
      #10; j = 0; k = 0; 
      #10; j = 1; k = 1; 
      #10; j = 0; k = 1; 
      #10; j = 0; k = 0; 
    end 
    
    initial begin
      $monitor($time, "\t clk = %b j = %b k = %b q = %b",clk,j,k,q);
      #60 $finish;
    end

endmodule
</pre></code>
```

```
//Output

Parsing design file 'design.sv'
Parsing design file 'testbench.sv'
Top Level Modules:
JK_TB
TimeScale is 1 ns / 1 ns
Starting vcs inline pass...

1 module and 0 UDP read.
recompiling module JK_TB

rm -f _cuarc\*.so csrc\*.so pre_vcsobj_\*.so share_vcsobj\*.so
if \[ -x ../simv \]; then chmod a-x ../simv; fi
g++  -o ../simv      -m32 -m32 -rdynamic  -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'/simv.daidir -Wl,-rpath=./simv.daidir -Wl,-rpath=/apps/vcsmx/vcs/S-2021.09/linux/lib -L/apps/vcsmx/vcs/S-2021.09/linux/lib  -Wl,-rpath-link=./ -Wl,--no-as-needed   objs/amcQw_d.o   \_322_archive_1.so  SIM_l.o       rmapats_mop.o rmapats.o rmar.o rmar_nd.o  rmar_llvm_0_1.o rmar_llvm_0_0.o           -lvirsim -lerrorinf -lsnpsmalloc -lvfs    -lvcsnew -lsimprofile -luclinative /apps/vcsmx/vcs/S-2021.09/linux/lib/vcs_tls.o   -Wl,-whole-archive  -lvcsucli    -Wl,-no-whole-archive          /apps/vcsmx/vcs/S-2021.09/linux/lib/vcs_save_restore_new.o /apps/vcsmx/vcs/S-2021.09/linux/lib/ctype-stubs_32.a -ldl  -lc -lm -lpthread -ldl
../simv up to date
CPU time: .215 seconds to compile + .404 seconds to elab + .220 seconds to link
Chronologic VCS simulator copyright 1991-2021
Contains Synopsys proprietary information.
Compiler version S-2021.09; Runtime version S-2021.09;  Mar 18 14:44 2024
0    clk = 0 j = 0 k = 1 q = 0
5    clk = 1 j = 0 k = 1 q = 0
10   clk = 0 j = 1 k = 0 q = 0
15   clk = 1 j = 1 k = 0 q = 0
20   clk = 0 j = 0 k = 0 q = 0
25   clk = 1 j = 0 k = 0 q = 0
30   clk = 0 j = 1 k = 1 q = 0
35   clk = 1 j = 1 k = 1 q = 0
40   clk = 0 j = 0 k = 1 q = 0
45   clk = 1 j = 0 k = 1 q = 0
50   clk = 0 j = 0 k = 0 q = 0
55   clk = 1 j = 0 k = 0 q = 0
$finish called from file "testbench.sv", line 28.
$finish at simulation time                   60
V C S   S i m u l a t i o n   R e p o r t
Time: 60 ns
CPU Time:      0.540 seconds;       Data structure size:   0.0Mb
Mon Mar 18 14:44:47 2024
```

Comment: I have used continuous assignment so I need to make s and r wire type

Comment: After removing removing initialization of s and r still output remains same and is indifferent towards the values of J and K

Comment: Recommend adding an asynchronous reset input to the flops and model the reset behavior in the code to set all the flop outputs to 0.   Search 'verilog flip flop reset' if you don't know how to do this.  Assert the reset at t=0 in the testbench, hold the reset for little bit and release.  You have some outputs at x starting at t=0 which propagate causing behavior you don't want.  Putting initial values on the signals is not a good way to model reset in this design.